# Proximity Card Reader with SDK for C#

Tags: c#, nfc

Don't know if this is the right place for this question :$

I've developed a C# (VS 2013) application that controls access to a building through a Biometric Device, now I've been requested to integrate a Proximity Card reader. The thing is that in order to facilitate the integration with the development I have to propose the right device, I've done a lot of research but I can't find a device with an SDK that allows me to integrate it with my development.

Do you know which brand provides such a thing (The device and the SDK)?

or if you have had any experience doing something similar I'd like to be guided.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Really? What about the devices you looked in to made you think you could not use the development kit? Can you cite specific examples of products you looked in to and why they would not work?

Comment: Hello Scott, I didn't say I could not use the SDK, I said that I'm looking for a device that comes with an SDK. ECL-ACC950, ECL-ACC995V2  from Eclipse Security. I asked them for the SDK but the answer was "Unfortunately at this moment we do not have an sdk available for this unit" I've done the same with other 4 companies.

Comment: maybe my question should be: Is there any generic SDK that I can use for any Proximity Card Reader Device?

Comment: There is no generic SDK, a SDK will either be device specific or the device emulates a keyboard and when you scan a card it will "type" the text that was on the card out.

Comment: I understand, would you suggest a specific brand that you know comes with an SDK?